# How to find the number of element in Hashmap in java?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```
System.out.println("elements="+maptabcolname.values());
```

Showing result : elements=[[aa, bb, cc, dd]] and

```
System.out.println("count elements="+maptabcolname.size());
```

Showing result : count elements=1   (here I want 4, since I have 4 elements separated by commas)
NB: here **maptabcolname** is a hashmap. 
Any help ? (I am using jdk 1.7)

Comment: Does your hashmap contain **one** `ArrayList` with **four** elements?

Comment: since `maptabcolname` contains only 1 element.

Comment: `size` will return the correct number of key-value pairs. Can you post the full code that actually shows this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing `System.out.println("elements="+maptabcolname.values().size());`

`.values()` returns an array of values in the map. Since you want the amount of those values, `.size()` will accomplish that for you.

Comment: `maptabcolname.values().size()` and `maptabcolname.size()` is the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It's showing result : count elements=[4] . But I want in integer. Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("elements="+maptabcolname.values().size());
```

Should work

Edit:

Without any fancy counting:

```
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(maptabcolname.values().toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "")));
```

Comment: `maptabcolname.values().size()` and `maptabcolname.size()` is the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
It's showing result : count elements=[4] . But I want in integer.  Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Your output shows two square brackets, so the `Map` contains 1 value, which is a `List` of 4 values.

To confirm, try:

```
for (Object value : maptabcolname.values())
    System.out.println(value.getClass().getName());
```

It'll print the type of value, e.g. `java.util.ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you have a map where values are lists and want a sum of sizes of these lists, is this correct?

A simple method should solve this problem:

```
public int count(Map<?, List<?>> map) {
    return map.values().stream().mapToInt(List::size).sum();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer:(It's simple )

Take a ArrayList then cast it and find the size of the arraylist. Here it is :

```
ArrayList count = new ArrayList();
count=(ArrayList) maptabcolname.get("k1"); //here "k1" is Key
System.out.println("number of elements="+count.size());
```

It will show the size. (Give suggestion). It's working.